# How to scale Rails applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I use apache and puma to deploy app. I use PostgreSQL. [Code on github](https://github.com/starwars25/Project). My apps are slow. when I generate several thousand rows in one table, productivity starts to get worse but still acceptable. I still can process 5 requests per second. When I added one million rows to one table, one query is executed in 8 seconds, and views seem to be generated forever. I added indexes and wrote raw SQL queries several times, but productivity is still very slow.

Where can I start optimizing rails application? How can I reach at least 50 requests per second?

Comment: First you need to identify the root cause. Are the database queries slow - what if you run that queries directly on the database without Rails? Are there too many request (N+1 queries)? Do you load too many objects into the memory?

Comment: I'm asking this since you mention it are course projects: Are you measuring in the production environment? Because the default development environment is not designed to scale, but to ease development.

Comment: all before my comment should be followed also I can add one you can use bullet for n+1 http://railscasts.com/episodes/372-bullet?view=asciicast read this also for counter cache and for prod increase buffer size maxclient for pg concurrent ness

Answer (score 4):

I recommend setting up [Mini Profiler](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler) to try to identify your bottlenecks. In particular look for the [N+1 problem](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations) (consider using [Bullet](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) if this *is* an issue).

Avoid looping over all your rows and instantiating a model for every one, thus sucking up memory:

```
User.all.each do # Bad
User.find_each do # Better
```

Use pagination (check out [Kaminari](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) or [WillPaginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate)) to avoid rendering pages with too many rows.

Answer (score 0):

Before optimizing - gather statistics (for example use request-log-analyzer gem) and determine which requests take the most in average slowness.

For example you may have a 8-seconds request, that is executed once a week, and a 0.5-second one, which runs every second, to make app faster first optimize the latter.

For slow requests - just look into their logs and further narrow down bottlenecks - db/views/etc.

Then go generic advice - "no code runs faster than no code", before going into raw SQL queries, writing C extensions etc. first look into complexity of your algorithms, poorly written O(n) will run faster than highly-optimized O(n^2), O(1) faster than O(n)

More specific to web programming - every query to anything external (db/webservices/memcache/etc.) costs time, transferring lots of data counts too, avoid separate querying each element in collection, if you can fetch them all at once or in less number of requests (rails has eager loading for associations for this very reason)

First i'd look into excessive db querying, remove unnecessary queries and look into execution plans (aka `explain ..`) for those that remain

Third thing is garbage collection, but I don't think it's a bottleneck for you at the moment